# Sync clock on Windows XP machine to external (non-domain, non-workgroup) Windows Server 2008 R2 machine

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-xp, time, time-synchronization

I have two machines and I'd like their clocks to be in sync for various reasons.  Machine 1 is an XP machine located in the office.  Machine 2 is a VPS hosted by a third party running Windows Server 2008 R2.  These machines are not in any kind of workgroup or on a domain together. They are completely separate machines.

Machine 2 is currently syncing once a week to time.windows.com.  The clock on Machine 2 does seem to wander a bit within that week interval.  What I would like to do is have Machine 1 set its clock based on the clock of Machine 2.

I have tried configuring w32tm on the XP machine. This is what I used for configuration:

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"<ip address of machine 2>"
```

However, whenever I issue the `/resync` command I get "The computer did not resync because no time data was available".  I have made sure to start the windows time service on machine 2, and I have added firewall exceptions for UDP port 123.

Is there something I need to configure on Machine 2 (other than just starting the time service) in order to get it to respond?

Edit: I have also run `w32tm /config /reliable:YES /update` on Machine 2.  I am still getting "The computer did not resync because no time data was available".  Is there something else I'm missing?

**Edit 2:** The solution I used was most closely related to the answer I marked as correct.  However, this article offered additional registry tweaks that worked in my case: http://www.articlesbase.com/networks-articles/how-to-configure-windows-server-as-a-ntp-server-108481.html

Comment: Are either machines a member of *any* AD domain, even if they're not in the same one?

Comment: If the clock skews during the week you can set a polling interval (mdmarra has discussed this in the past).  Another option would be to set both to use the same 3rd party source.

Comment: @MDMarra Unfortunately no - just two independent machines :(

Comment: That's actually better for your needs in this case. At least as it related to time services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine 2 needs to be confiugred as an authoritative time source.  Ie. NTPSERVER = 1. From the registry key: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpServer]` Enabled = 1

Alternatively you can do that via the command `w32tm /config /reliable:YES /update`

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't seem to work.  Somewhere along the way I saw some text saying that /reliable:YES was only valid for domain controllers?  Unfortunately these machines are not on any domain or workgroup, just standalone machines

Comment: I'm marking this as correct, as this was part of the solution.  However, I needed to change the AnnounceFlags as well.  This url solved my problem: http://www.articlesbase.com/networks-articles/how-to-configure-windows-server-as-a-ntp-server-108481.html

Answer (score 3):

There are also some good ports of NTP reference code that I like to use on Windows machines.  Look at

```
  http://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm#ntp_nt_stable
```

Answer (score 2):

"[The W32Time service is not a full-featured NTP solution that meets time-sensitive application needs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263%28WS.10%29.aspx)."

I would switch to a standard NTP service.
Some hints here http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/setup.html